# Do exercise or exercises

Tags: word-choice

Can I use "exercise" as shown in my examples?

1. "I do exercise."
2. "I do exercises."
3. "I do an exercise."
4. "I do some exercise."
5. "I do some exercises."
6. "I don't do any exercise."
7. "I don't do any experiences."
8. "Do you do any exercise?"
9. "Do you do any exercises?"
10. "Do you do an exercise every morning?"

Comment: surely a quick web search will give examples.  can you make this more focussed. what are you specifically unsure of in the use of the noun "exercise".

Comment: I am.not sure if my sentences are correct and the word "exercise" is used correctly in each of them?

Comment: Yes, so.... do a quick web search and find some examples.   When you've narrowed down your question it might be answerable.  As it stands it is just a tick/cross exercise for us, not a question.

Comment: The one you are missing is "I exercise".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 is the strangest, asking a question about *one* exercise, which sort of implies that you have a specific one in mind, or that all exercises are interchangeable. This is probably not what you meant to say.

The rest of the sentences are all grammatical, other than the misplaced word in 7, but they have different meanings.

"Exercise" as an uncountable noun means physical activity in general, usually aerobics—something intended to improve fitness. On the other hand, "exercises" are small actions you practice to build a skill. They may simply be types of exercise; sit-ups and jumping jacks are two exercises that also constitute exercise.

But "an exercise" can also refer to things unrelated to fitness. It's repetitive practice for any skill, usually performed in a prescribed way, such as a hand exercise for a guitarist, or math exercises for a student. Furthermore, not every type of exercise would be referred to as "an exercise," such as any kind of sport, or anything done freely or for fun without deliberate repetition (going for a jog, free swimming, etc.).

This extends to all of your examples. 1, 4, 6, and 8 refer to fitness-oriented activities. 2, 3, 5, 7, and 9 refer to some kind of repetitive skill-building activity, which needs a little more specificity to be meaningful—even in the negative and interrogative forms, where, technically, the listener should list exercises that they do of *any* kind, but in practice they will probably want to know what kind of answer you're expecting, as answering a question about math homework with "yes, I do bicep curls" would be very embarrassing.